# C struct pointer types are the same but still fails

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, declaration

I am building a C test program on Linux.

Why does this code compilation fail below? After `list_t` is type-defined, shouldn't the compiler understand later that it is the same type as a `struct list` ?

The attempt to create a new list item using malloc() fails with `error: invalid type argument`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list
{
    struct list *next_ptr; 
    int value;
}list_t;

int main()
{
   list_t myList;
   myList->next_ptr = malloc(sizeof(list_t)); // This fails
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should show the exact and complete error message you got.

Comment: `myList->next_ptr` --> `myList.next_ptr` and you are done (`myList` is not a pointer)

Comment: _Side note:_ What you're calling a "list", I'd call a "node" [an element of a linked list]. I'd change all `list` to `node`. Then, I'd define a list: `typedef struct { node_t *head; node_t *tail; } list_t;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myList->next_ptr` should be `myList.next_ptr` because `myList` is not a pointer.

Comment: My bad. Stupid mistake. Apologies.

Comment: @engineer999 the compiler *tells you this*